# Assign ID for coordinates with several points

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, grouping

In ArcGIS pro I have a point layer with XY-coordinates. At each coordinate there are several points with different timestamps. I would like to give each coordinate an ID, for example to be able to display the number of coordinates in a diagram. One thought of mine was to join the X and Y coordinates. However, on the one hand this does not look nice and on the other hand it is not always practicable. Is there a better way to do this or or is it better to export the table to excel?

[image: Attribute table with coordinates]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking to do, you need to identify groups of points that share identical X and Y coordinates and give each of those groups an ID. Here is one possible solution.

First, create a new field (e.g., POINT_XY) with type double. Then use the Calculate Field to populate it with:

```
POINT_XY = !POINT_X! * !POINT_Y!
```

There are other ways you could identify unique combinations of X and Y coordinates, but I think it's extremely unlikely you could produce the same product by multiplying them together given how many digits you have in the input fields.

Then, run the [Find Identical](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm) tool to identify unique values in the new POINT_XY field. This will produce a new table with two fields: IN_FID and FEAT_SEQ. IN_FID is the FID of each feature from your original table, and FEAT_SEQ is the group ID for points with the same X and Y coordinates.

After that, there are a variety of ways to summarize or display how many points fall at each shared location. You could join the new table to your original attribute table using OBJECTID and IN_FID. You could summarize how many points are in each group using a Pivot Table or similar methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly for me, especially the Find Identifical tool was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to simply use the [Collects Events](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/collect-events.htm) tool, this will give you a count on the stack of points, a single point to represent the stack and the OBJECTID value is essentially the grouping ID.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that tool. Much simpler than the solution I proposed.